# How do I see the renamed files in Python script output?

Tags: python, macos

I renamed files in a certain folder, I tried to show a list of original files, and a list of renamed files. The problem is, the two output of the print function is the same, where it should be different.

This is my code:

```
import os 
import string 
list = os.listdir(r"/Users/air/Desktop/book vocab/b CS tutr") 
print list 

os.chdir(r"/Users/air/Desktop/book vocab/b CS tutr")

for file in list: 
    os.rename (file, file.translate(None,'12345'))

print list
```

both output are the original file names, where I expected the second output should be the renamed file names.

Comment: You should not use the variable name `list`; it masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns a list of strings. That list of strings, once returned, has no connection anymore with the original directory listing.

In other words, the variable `list` will *not* change when you rename files. Call `os.listdir()` again to get the new, updated listing.

Alternatively, update your list *as well* with the new names:

```
path = "/Users/air/Desktop/book vocab/b CS tutr"
filenames = os.listdir(path) 
print filenames

os.chdir(path)

for i, filename in enumerate(filenames): 
    newname = filename.translate(None, '12345')
    os.rename(filename, newname)
    filenames[i] = newname

print filenames
```

I used a different name for the filenames list here to not mask the [built-in type name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).